# How to add page break at end of bulk documents?

Tags: macos, ms-word, applescript, automator

I have several hundred short documents (mostly one page) that I'm wanting to combine into one large document. 
I have managed to get the combining action down pat (using Automator) though Word adds in the next document directly after the previous, without a page break.

After extensive searching, it seems that the best option would be to open each document, add a page break at the end, and then save.

Is there a way I can do this for multiple documents at once? Using Automator or AppleScript?

Comment: Usually, Word has the merge feature built-in, so you don't need to use Automator for this. What is your Word version?

Comment: I'm using version 16.20  
I was unable to find a merge feature. And inserting text from document only allows one document at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in AppleScript to insert a page break at the end of a document. I'm sorry I don't have Word to test it.

`tell application "Microsoft Word"
    insert break at (after last character of active document)
end tell`

**EDIT: Added 2018-12-23**

```
tell application "Finder" to set allFiles to every file of (choose folder)

set outputFile to (choose folder) & "output.docx" -- or whatever 

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate 
    make new document 

    repeat with i from (count allFiles) to 1 by -1 
        display dialog (item i of allFiles as text)

        insert file at text object of selection file name (item i of allFiles as text)

        if i > 1 then 
            insert break at (after last character of active document) 
        end if 
    end repeat 

    save as active document file name outputFile
end tell
```

It may need some debugging, but that's more or less how it can work. Please let us know if you're not somewhat fluent with AppleScript and need help debugging.

Comment: Thank you for the script! 
I opened 3 documents to test the script on, and it only worked on the first document opened. 
I'm looking for something that will do several documents at once, and then save them as well.

Comment: That script is just the basic command. You would need to incorporate it into the rest of your document handling (however you've already accomplished that) so that before you open a subsequent document to append to the previous document(s) you'd run that to get a page break in there.

Comment: Desmond, to improve your answer, perhaps you could demonstrate how to do what you’re describing ?  Could you advise Jessie by way of example how to open multiple Word documents and stitch them together with a page break between them ?

Comment: You are right, CJK. Without Word I can't validate this.`tell application "Finder" to set allFiles to every file of (choose folder)
set outputFile to (choose folder) & "output.docx" -- or whatever
tell application "Microsoft Word"
 activate
 make new document
 repeat with i from (count allFiles) to 1 by -1
  display dialog (item i of allFiles as text)
  insert file at text object of selection file name (item i of allFiles as text)
  if i > 1 then
   insert break at (after last character of active document)
  end if
 end repeat
 save as active document file name outputFile
end tell`

Comment: It may need some debugging, but that's more or less how it can work. Please let us know, Jessie, if you're not somewhat fluent with AppleScript and need help debugging.

Comment: You may have been better off editing your answer and adding that code, which can then be formatted over separate lines.  Adding big edits in the comments section isn't the best method, both in terms of making your answer visible to users and making it readable when there's a code block.  Well done for adding the extra detail, though.  Hopefully Jessie appreciates the extra hints.

Comment: Thanks, CJK! I'm still learning the best practices on here. Cheers!

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I took the liberty of editing your answer to incorporate your new code into it.  Feel free to edit it any way you like - I just did a copy-n-paste, and separated the lines out.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but it comes up as the first answer when googling "applescript word page break". Anyway, I have MS Word and can confirm that the script works as intended. This answer should be marked as correct.